# Unexpected output when uses getline() to read entire line from stdin?

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on c,  following is my code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        char* str = NULL;
        size_t n;

        printf("Enter the string : \n");
        getline(&str, &n, stdin);
        printf("Initial string is : (%s)\n", str);
        return 0;
}
```

When i run the above program it gives following output:

```
Enter the string :
bsalunke
Initial string is : (bsalunke
)
```

What might be the reason of unexpected string getting stored in `str` pointer(i.e. it is a string with many white spaces) ? 
Im using gcc 4.1.2 version on linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the man page of getline

> getline()  reads  an entire line from stream, storing the address of
>   the buffer containing the text into *lineptr. The buffer is
>   null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.

I think that explains it. It is not a string with many white spaces, it is a string ending with a new line.

Answer (score 0):

The program does not work because you are writing code which you don't understand. You cannot "store a string in a pointer". You need to study arrays and pointers.

You are attempting to store data at a random memory location, without allocating any memory for the data. This is completely undefined behavior.

Comment: Though it does look like that's happening, `getline` allocates the correct sized buffer if passed a NULL pointer.